# Puppeteer `textContent of undefined`

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape some stats from basketball-reference using Puppeteer, but having some troubles accessing `textContent` of each of the `<tr>` in the table. The DOM structure looks something like

```
<table id="per_game_stats">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-stat="g">22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-stat="g">23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-stat="g">24</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my Puppeteer code that tries to access those values

```
const statsPerGame = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table#per_game_stats > tbody > tr'))
  return rows.map((element) => element.innerHTML)
})

console.log(statsPerGame) // ... '<td data-stat="g">22</td>'
```

Okay, so `element` definitely exists. I want to get the value using `textContent`, but an error is thrown

```
const statsPerGame = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table#per_game_stats > tbody > tr'))
  return rows.map((element) => element.querySelector('td[data-stat="g"]').textContent)
})

// TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You don't have `textContent` anywhere?

Comment: @VLAZ  I'm not sure what you mean, but `textContent` is a property on the HTML DOM object. Since `element` is a DOM element, `element.textContent` shouldn't have thrown an error.

Comment: I mean that none of the code you've shown tries to get `textContent`. Is this the code you're using or is there something missing?

Comment: @VLAZ my bad, I updated the code!

Comment: OK, in this case - are you sure that every single row has something that matches a `td[data-stat="g"]` selector? The error seems to indicate that there is at least one <tr> that doesn't have a <td> with a `data-stat="g"` attribute.

Comment: `TypeError: element.querySelector(...) is null` for me. Index 22 in the array is null if you use `querySelector`.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh. Index 22 is a `<tr>` header. It isn't a player row, and doesn't have the `data-stat="g"` attribute. Thank you thank you thank you!